# Should we redact/remove IP addresses?

Tags: discussion, policy

I have just edited this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349851/ssh-packet-write-wait-broken-pipe) and I'm now somehow concerned about this person's security.

Generally, when users are requested to give back debug output a lot of private information could leak. Some are more and some less concerning/consequential for the poster.

**Does StackExchange have a policy about this?**

Would there be a tool to i.e. to filter IP adresses and replace it with generic ones (to still make the output useful/readable)?

I don't want to discuss this particular case, but want to know in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no tool I know of. I just edited that question and replaced the IP with `123.456.789.10`.

The only thing to be careful about when making this sort of change is keeping the IPs consistent. For example, if the OP is mentioning two IPs and they're on the same subnet, make sure any dummy IPs you might edit into the post also have the same dummy subnet.

For more details on how to treat sensitive information, see the main meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/203101).

Comment: @hyph um. OK. Done

Comment: You should read [RFC5737](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc5737): "IPv4 Address Blocks Reserved for Documentation". It lists three ranges that can safely be used in documentation and examples, and which are probably preferable over IP addresses that are invalid (456 and 789 cannot be described in 8 bits, and 123/8 is probably assigned to someone)